# LibreOffice - Relative link to another .docx on local system not working

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I am trying to insert a link on **first.docx** file pointing into **second.docx** file, using a relative path on the file system (both files are located on the same directory, named **parentfolder**).
Unfortunately, setting the path simply as **second.docx** does not seem to work. Nevertheless, when I make use of the **absolute path** ( **file:///C:/Users/parentfolder/second.docx** ) it works fine and opens the second.docx document.

Am I doing something wrong or does LibreOffice not support relative paths for documents on local storage?

**LibreOffice version: 7.1.5.2 (x64), Operating System: Windows 10**

Comment: How are you inserting the link?

Comment: Hi, @ReddyLutonadio and thanks for the response, I select a text string in the doc content > Insert > Hyperlink... > On the left sidebar I select "Document" option > Document Path: "second.docx" > Apply > OK

When I click on this link I get the following:

"second.docx" cannot be passed to an external application to open it (e.g., it might not be an absolute URL, or might denote no existing file).

Comment: Try this: On Document Path, you must enter the full path (select the file by clicking the icon on the right). Then on Text option, enter second.docx. On the page, second.docx will be shown but clicking the ling will lead to the correct file.

Comment: But this is not what I want to achieve... I want to have a folder with these documents linked to each other, and be able to send this folder to someone else and the documents still be linkable between them in his/her local storage